# How to make a graphic fully display in Row (and possibly related constructs)?

Tags: formatting, display, row

My problem is likely fairly simple and possibly relates to some preset behaviour of how items are displayed. Or maybe I just do not understand something basic, I am no Mathematica expert, just casual user.

Consider this code (it is fairly specific case, but can be hopefully easily generalized to similar issues):

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], Style[Text["one of", {0, 1}], 40]}]
Row[{a, Graphics[{Arrow[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], Style[Text["one of", {0, 1}], 40]}], b}]
```

The output I get is

[image]

where in the latter case the text "one of" is squeezed inbetween the `a` and `b`.

How can I make the row display the full text, more similar to the output of the first line (I am interested in the text, I can play with the size and relative position of the arrow on my own)?
I need that so that I can export something similar with the text fully readable.

I would like this to be included in a sequence of graphics, and while putting everything into one graphic and offsetting individual elements is a possibility, I am looking for a more elegant solution using Row or similar display function.

Thanks for help, if this is easy to google, I am missing some required concepts or keywords.

Edit: I am on Mathmetica 13.0.1.0, but I do not expect this to play a role.

Comment: `GraphicsRow[{a, Graphics[{Arrow[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], Style[Text["one of", {0, 1}], 40]}], b}]` or `Grid[{{a, Graphics[{Arrow[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], Style[Text["one of", {0, 1}], 40]}], b}}]`?

Comment: @MelaGo Thank you, I guess I noticed this function at some point, but did not recall it now. It does achieve what I asked for in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `Row[...]` with `Style` with the option [ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1,1}](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html)

```
Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] & @
 Row[{a, 
     Graphics[{Arrow[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], Style[Text["one of", {0, 1}], 40]}],
     b}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly certain how you want the positioning to be, but perhaps this can give you some sort of guiding principle

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], Style[Text["a", {-2, 1}], 13], 
  Style[Text["one of", {0, 1}], 40], Style[Text["b", {2, 1}], 13]}]
```

> [image: res]

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to sequentially show multiple graphics. I did not specify it in the OP and will update it. While your answer suggest a workaround, I will try to wait whether someone suggests a more natural solution